# Unusual Core Data Behavior - Save one object effects another?

Tags: macos, swift, core-data

So I'm trying to learn Swift, and I'm sure I've done something wrong, but I cannot figure out what that might be.

I'm writing a note-taking application to help myself get up to speed with the language. It features a table view (populated by an NSArrayController). Clicking on a note in the table view brings up a view controller that displays the title and body of the note. Clicking the add button creates a new note managed object and passes that to the same view controller as that used for edit.

When editing a note, users who select some text and press command-l can create a new note with the title equal to the selected text.

Everything works great except the command-l. That behavior is most unusual and, I'm sure, is something I've caused.

It goes like this:

1. create a note and fill out the title and body. Let's say it's called 'First' and the body is 'this is the first, not the second.'
2. select some text ('second') and press command-l. This saves the current note, creates a new managed object, fills in the title ('second'), and displays that in the view controller. enter the body text ('this is the second')
3. save the note.
4. The view controller now lists two notes, as it should. Clicking the first note ('first') now shows the description of the second. ('this is the second')

Here's some code:

From the main (table-view) controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier=="CreateNote" {
        let nextViewController = segue.destinationController as! DetailViewController
        nextViewController.managedContext=self.managedContext
        nextViewController.note = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Note", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext!) as! Note
    }
    else if segue.identifier=="EditNote" {
        let theSelection = tableView.selectedRow
        let theNote = noteArrayController?.arrangedObjects[theSelection] as! Note
        let nextViewController = segue.destinationController as! DetailViewController
        nextViewController.managedContext=self.managedContext
        nextViewController.note = theNote
    }
}
```

From the detail view controller:

```
import AppKit

class DetailViewController: NSViewController, KeyNotificationProtocol {

    @IBOutlet weak var noteTitle: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet var noteBody: TWTextView!

    @IBAction func backButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        saveNote()
        if historyStack.isNotEmpty() {
            note=findNoteByName(historyStack.pop())
            loadNote()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func dismissButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        saveNote()
        self.dismissController(self)
    }
    var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
    var note: Note?
    var noteNameToLoad: String?
    var historyStack = Stack<String>()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadNote()
        noteBody.keyDelegate = self

        var requestArray: [KeyRequest] = []

        requestArray.append(KeyRequest(theFlags: [NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask],
            theKey: "l",
            theTag: "link",
            theFunc: self.createLink))

        noteBody.keysOfInterest=requestArray
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear() {
        saveNote()
    }

    func keypressWasReceived(keypress: KeyNotificationData) {
        keypress.keypressRequest.funcToCall()
    }

    func createLink() {
        print("create link!")
        if(noteBody.selectedRange().length>0) {
            saveNote()
            if let swRange = noteBody.string?.rangeFromNSRange(noteBody.selectedRange()) {
                let selectedText = noteBody.string!.substringWithRange(swRange)
                let tempNote=findNoteByName(selectedText)
                if(tempNote==nil) {
                    historyStack.push((note?.title)!)
                    self.note = (NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Note", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext!) as! Note)
                    self.note!.title=selectedText
                    self.note!.attributedBody=NSAttributedString(string: "New note")
                    loadNote()
                }
                else {
                    print("note exists")
                }
            }

        }
    }

    func saveNote() -> BooleanType {
        if (managedContext?.hasChanges != nil) {
            self.note?.title=noteTitle.stringValue
            self.note?.attributedBody=noteBody.textStorage
            var saved = false

            do {
                try managedContext?.save()
                saved = true
            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error saving \(error)", terminator: "")
            }

            return saved
        }
        else {
            return true
        }

    }

    func loadNote() {
        if self.note?.title==nil {
            self.note?.title=""
        }
        noteTitle.stringValue = (self.note?.title)!

        if(self.note?.attributedBody?.length>0) {
            noteBody.textStorage?.setAttributedString((self.note?.attributedBody)!)
        }
        else if(self.note?.body?.characters.count>0) {
            noteBody.textStorage?.setAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: (self.note?.body)!))
        }
        else {
            noteBody.textStorage?.setAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: ""))
        }

    }

    func findNoteByName(noteName: String) -> Note? {
        let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Note")
        freq.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title == %@", noteName)
        var result: [Note]=[]
        do {
            result = try managedContext?.executeFetchRequest(freq) as! [Note]
        }
        catch let theError as NSError {
            print(theError)
            result=[]
        }

        if result.count>0 {
            return result[0]
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }    
}
```

Creating the first note:

[image]

After pressing command-l, the first note is saved and the second note is created:

[image]

After saving the second note (clicking done), returning to the table view, and clicking the first:

[image]

So, in an attempt to find out what's up, I added KVO for managedObjectContext notifications. I did this in the appdelegate where all the core data stuff is set up:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "shitHappened:", name: NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification, object: managedObjectContext)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "shitHappened:", name: NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, object: managedObjectContext)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "shitHappened:", name: NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification, object: managedObjectContext)
}

func shitHappened(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("-- something happened with core data --")
    print(sender)
}
```

Monitoring the output generated by my observer, I **do not see** the first note being updated & saved such that the body is set to that of the second! Here's the data from that. At the very end of this log data, there's a notification saying that First Note has been modified. Where?!

```
-- something happened with core data --
NSConcreteNotification 0x608000045c10 {name = NSObjectsChangedInManagingContextNotification; object = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6180001c01e0>; userInfo = {
    inserted = "{(\n    <testwiki.Note: 0x6100000a8fa0> (entity: Note; id: 0x610000020b40 <x-coredata:///Note/tBCC61422-BDB8-44EB-A1A0-D32126C892354> ; data: {\n    attributedBody = nil;\n    body = nil;\n    title = \"\";\n})\n)}";
    managedObjectContext = "<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6180001c01e0>";
}}
create link!
-- something happened with core data --
NSConcreteNotification 0x61000005af40 {name = NSObjectsChangedInManagingContextNotification; object = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6180001c01e0>; userInfo = {
    managedObjectContext = "<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6180001c01e0>";
    updated = "{(\n    <testwiki.Note: 0x6100000a8fa0> (entity: Note; id: 0x610000020b40 <x-coredata:///Note/tBCC61422-BDB8-44EB-A1A0-D32126C892354> ; data: {\n    attributedBody = \"This is the first, not the second.{\\n    NSFont = \\\"\\\\\\\"Helvetica 12.00 pt. P [] (0x610000247e90) fobj=0x101b11ca0, spc=3.33\\\\\\\"\\\";\\n    NSParagraphStyle = \\\"Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\\\\n    28L,\\\\n    56L,\\\\n    84L,\\\\n    112L,\\\\n    140L,\\\\n    168L,\\\\n    196L,\\\\n    224L,\\\\n    252L,\\\\n    280L,\\\\n    308L,\\\\n    336L\\\\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\\\\n), Lists (\\\\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0\\\";\\n}\";\n    body = nil;\n    title = \"The First Note\";\n})\n)}";
}}
-- something happened with core data --
NSConcreteNotification 0x61000004dc50 {name = NSManagingContextWillSaveChangesNotification; object = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6180001c01e0>}
-- something happened with core data --
NSConcreteNotification 0x61000024c870 {name = NSManagingContextDidSaveChangesNotification; object = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6180001c01e0>; userInfo = {
    inserted = "{(\n    <testwiki.Note: 0x6100000a8fa0> (entity: Note; id: 0x610000228e00 <x-coredata://18C6EA07-F369-4289-B333-53326C2B9DFE/Note/p226> ; data: {\n    attributedBody = \"This is the first, not the second.{\\n    NSFont = \\\"\\\\\\\"Helvetica 12.00 pt. P [] (0x610000247e90) fobj=0x101b11ca0, spc=3.33\\\\\\\"\\\";\\n    NSParagraphStyle = \\\"Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\\\\n    28L,\\\\n    56L,\\\\n    84L,\\\\n    112L,\\\\n    140L,\\\\n    168L,\\\\n    196L,\\\\n    224L,\\\\n    252L,\\\\n    280L,\\\\n    308L,\\\\n    336L\\\\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\\\\n), Lists (\\\\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0\\\";\\n}\";\n    body = nil;\n    title = \"The First Note\";\n})\n)}";
    updated = "{(\n)}";
}}
loadNote
Optional("second")
Optional(New note{
})
-- something happened with core data --
NSConcreteNotification 0x610000053a10 {name = NSObjectsChangedInManagingContextNotification; object = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6180001c01e0>; userInfo = {
    inserted = "{(\n    <testwiki.Note: 0x6100000a9a80> (entity: Note; id: 0x6100002298c0 <x-coredata:///Note/tBCC61422-BDB8-44EB-A1A0-D32126C892355> ; data: {\n    attributedBody = \"New note{\\n}\";\n    body = nil;\n    title = second;\n})\n)}";
    managedObjectContext = "<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6180001c01e0>";
}}
-- something happened with core data --
NSConcreteNotification 0x61800005cbc0 {name = NSObjectsChangedInManagingContextNotification; object = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6180001c01e0>; userInfo = {
    managedObjectContext = "<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6180001c01e0>";
    updated = "{(\n    <testwiki.Note: 0x6100000a9a80> (entity: Note; id: 0x6100002298c0 <x-coredata:///Note/tBCC61422-BDB8-44EB-A1A0-D32126C892355> ; data: {\n    attributedBody = \"This is the second.{\\n    NSFont = \\\"\\\\\\\"Helvetica 12.00 pt. P [] (0x610000247e90) fobj=0x101b11ca0, spc=3.33\\\\\\\"\\\";\\n    NSParagraphStyle = \\\"Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\\\\n    28L,\\\\n    56L,\\\\n    84L,\\\\n    112L,\\\\n    140L,\\\\n    168L,\\\\n    196L,\\\\n    224L,\\\\n    252L,\\\\n    280L,\\\\n    308L,\\\\n    336L\\\\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\\\\n), Lists (\\\\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0\\\";\\n}\";\n    body = nil;\n    title = second;\n})\n)}";
}}
-- something happened with core data --
NSConcreteNotification 0x618000240d50 {name = NSManagingContextWillSaveChangesNotification; object = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6180001c01e0>}
-- something happened with core data --
NSConcreteNotification 0x61800005d970 {name = NSManagingContextDidSaveChangesNotification; object = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6180001c01e0>; userInfo = {
    inserted = "{(\n    <testwiki.Note: 0x6100000a9a80> (entity: Note; id: 0x61800003ac20 <x-coredata://18C6EA07-F369-4289-B333-53326C2B9DFE/Note/p227> ; data: {\n    attributedBody = \"This is the second.{\\n    NSFont = \\\"\\\\\\\"Helvetica 12.00 pt. P [] (0x610000247e90) fobj=0x101b11ca0, spc=3.33\\\\\\\"\\\";\\n    NSParagraphStyle = \\\"Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\\\\n    28L,\\\\n    56L,\\\\n    84L,\\\\n    112L,\\\\n    140L,\\\\n    168L,\\\\n    196L,\\\\n    224L,\\\\n    252L,\\\\n    280L,\\\\n    308L,\\\\n    336L\\\\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\\\\n), Lists (\\\\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0\\\";\\n}\";\n    body = nil;\n    title = second;\n})\n)}";
    updated = "{(\n)}";
}}
-- something happened with core data --
NSConcreteNotification 0x618000242310 {name = NSObjectsChangedInManagingContextNotification; object = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6180001c01e0>; userInfo = {
    managedObjectContext = "<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6180001c01e0>";
    updated = "{(\n    <testwiki.Note: 0x6100000a9a80> (entity: Note; id: 0x61800003ac20 <x-coredata://18C6EA07-F369-4289-B333-53326C2B9DFE/Note/p227> ; data: {\n    attributedBody = \"This is the second.{\\n    NSFont = \\\"\\\\\\\"Helvetica 12.00 pt. P [] (0x610000247e90) fobj=0x101b11ca0, spc=3.33\\\\\\\"\\\";\\n    NSParagraphStyle = \\\"Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\\\\n    28L,\\\\n    56L,\\\\n    84L,\\\\n    112L,\\\\n    140L,\\\\n    168L,\\\\n    196L,\\\\n    224L,\\\\n    252L,\\\\n    280L,\\\\n    308L,\\\\n    336L\\\\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\\\\n), Lists (\\\\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0\\\";\\n}\";\n    body = nil;\n    title = second;\n})\n)}";
}}
-- something happened with core data --
NSConcreteNotification 0x618000242f40 {name = NSManagingContextWillSaveChangesNotification; object = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6180001c01e0>}
-- something happened with core data --
NSConcreteNotification 0x608000046240 {name = NSManagingContextDidSaveChangesNotification; object = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6180001c01e0>; userInfo = {
    inserted = "{(\n)}";
    updated = "{(\n    <testwiki.Note: 0x6100000a9a80> (entity: Note; id: 0x61800003ac20 <x-coredata://18C6EA07-F369-4289-B333-53326C2B9DFE/Note/p227> ; data: {\n    attributedBody = \"This is the second.{\\n    NSFont = \\\"\\\\\\\"Helvetica 12.00 pt. P [] (0x610000247e90) fobj=0x101b11ca0, spc=3.33\\\\\\\"\\\";\\n    NSParagraphStyle = \\\"Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\\\\n    28L,\\\\n    56L,\\\\n    84L,\\\\n    112L,\\\\n    140L,\\\\n    168L,\\\\n    196L,\\\\n    224L,\\\\n    252L,\\\\n    280L,\\\\n    308L,\\\\n    336L\\\\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\\\\n), Lists (\\\\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0\\\";\\n}\";\n    body = nil;\n    title = second;\n})\n)}";
}}
about to segue to editNote
with title
Optional("The First Note")
Optional(This is the second.{
    NSFont = "\"Helvetica 12.00 pt. P [] (0x610000247e90) fobj=0x101b11ca0, spc=3.33\"";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0";
})
------------------------
loadNote
Optional("The First Note")
Optional(This is the second.{
    NSFont = "\"Helvetica 12.00 pt. P [] (0x610000247e90) fobj=0x101b11ca0, spc=3.33\"";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0";
})
-- something happened with core data --
NSConcreteNotification 0x618000241aa0 {name = NSObjectsChangedInManagingContextNotification; object = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6180001c01e0>; userInfo = {
    managedObjectContext = "<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6180001c01e0>";
    updated = "{(\n    <testwiki.Note: 0x6100000a8fa0> (entity: Note; id: 0x610000228e00 <x-coredata://18C6EA07-F369-4289-B333-53326C2B9DFE/Note/p226> ; data: {\n    attributedBody = \"This is the second.{\\n    NSFont = \\\"\\\\\\\"Helvetica 12.00 pt. P [] (0x610000247e90) fobj=0x101b11ca0, spc=3.33\\\\\\\"\\\";\\n    NSParagraphStyle = \\\"Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\\\\n    28L,\\\\n    56L,\\\\n    84L,\\\\n    112L,\\\\n    140L,\\\\n    168L,\\\\n    196L,\\\\n    224L,\\\\n    252L,\\\\n    280L,\\\\n    308L,\\\\n    336L\\\\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\\\\n), Lists (\\\\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0\\\";\\n}\";\n    body = nil;\n    title = \"The First Note\";\n})\n)}";
}}
```

Other notes: I'm watching for the command-l in a subclassed NSTextView with an overridden keyDown function.

Edit: I neglected to point out that if I create a long chain of notes, using command-l to go from one to the next, every note in that chain will have the same note body when I go back and look at them.

Comment: Is the problem `self.note?.attributedBody=noteBody.textStorage`? All attributedBodies point to the same textStorage.

Comment: That was it! So I had to change this line in saveNote():

self.note?.attributedBody=noteBody.textStorage

to these:

let attributedBody = NSAttributedString(attributedString: noteBody.textStorage!) 
self.note?.attributedBody=attributedBody

If you write up an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All attributedBodies point to the same textStorage.

Change

```
self.note?.attributedBody=noteBody.textStorage
```

to

```
self.note?.attributedBody = NSAttributedString(attributedString: noteBody.textStorage!)
```